# Visual Studio 2012 Keyboard Shortcut to cancel Edit.CompleteWord (opposite of Ctrl + Space)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts

In the text editor I have IntelliSense on and most of the time it is great for completing your word. I like it coming up when I start typing.
I also often use Ctrl + Space to bring up the suggestions.

I want to know if it is possible to 'cancel' the suggestions if you don't want to use the suggestions that particular time without using the mouse.

I currently have to click on the screen to take the focus away from the IntelliSense pop up so that when i press 'space' it doesn't populate the word with its suggestion.

Is there any way to do this other than unticking "Show completion list after a character is typed" in "Options \ Text Editor \ C# \ IntelliSense"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hitting escape should clear the suggestions list.

Comment: Thanks - so simple and didn't think of it!